# mod_rewrite to redirect to different virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd

The hostname where I want to redirect to looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName my.dav.hostname.com
       ErrorLog /var/log/open-xchange/dav-err.log
       TransferLog /var/log/open-xchange/dav-access.log
       <Proxy />
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/servlet/dav/ smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to do something like if someone goes to a URL my.hostname.com/dav, I want it to be rewritten to my.dav.hostname.com.. If the client goes to a URL other than `/dav`, he should *not* be redirected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName my.hostname.com
       ErrorLog /var/log/open-xchange/dav-err.log
       TransferLog /var/log/open-xchange/dav-access.log
       .. 
       ..
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm clueless on how I should proceed.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /servlet/webdav.infostore http://my.dav.hostname.com [L,NE,QSA]
```

As it actually redirects to my.dav.hostname.com which I don't want. What I want is for apache to transparently do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my.dav.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/dav/(.*)$ http://my.dav.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Personally I wouldn't use your subdomain structure though. It's better to use `dav.subdomain.domain.com` over `subdomain.dav.domain.com`.

Comment: I don't want a a redirect, I want apache to do it transparently. Sorry, I wasn't clear enough earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want apache to do this transparantly (ie. the URL in the browser must not change) you could just simply mount your DAV servlet in the other server too:

```
ProxyPass /dav/ ajp://localhost:8009/servlet/dav/ smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
```

Comment: That's not gonna work because then all requests starting going to dav servlet. I also tried it to add it under `<Location /dav`, but it seems, it's not possible